# print(icerik[0].text) IndexError: list index out of range error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.python.tc/python-nedir"
url_oku = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')
icerik = soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':'single-post-content'})
print(icerik[0].text)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hira\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\d.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(icerik[0].text)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Could you provide more information than a snippet of code and an error message? Because as it stands, there is no question here to answer, only stating the obvious: `icerik` is apparently an empty list because your `find_all` didn't find anything...

Comment: how can I pull site content?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code, the page doesn't contain `<div>` with class `single-post-content`. To get post content, try to get `<article>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
url = "http://www.python.tc/python-nedir"
url_oku = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_oku, 'html.parser')

icerik = soup.find('article',attrs={'class':'single-post'})
print(icerik.text)
```

This will print:

```
Python Nedir?               
  Ali Yaman  Yenilmez Mayıs 5, 2016 Programlama , Temel Programlama 14 Yorumlar 994 görüntüleme Python Dili Nedir? Python, Guido Van rossum adlı hollandalı bir programcı tarafından yazılmış bir programlama dilidir. Geliştirilmesine 1990 yılında başlayan Python; C ve C++ gibi programlama dillerine...

...and so on.
```